# Merging two rows having different value

Tags: db2

I have a Sample table:

```
Region    | OpenServices | DFC
Karaci    | 14           | 4
Lahore    | 13           | 3
Islamabad | 10           | 4
```

This is Second Table

```
Region    | OpenServices | DFC
Karaci    | 14           | 4
Lahore    | 10           | 3
Islamabad | 10           | 4
```

I want my Final table to look like

```
Region    | OpenServices | DFC
Karaci    | 14           | 4
Lahore    | 13 , 10      | 3
Islamabad | 10           | 4
```

Comment: This is what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output

Comment: What's your DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume LUW and a recent one. There you can use the `LISTAGG` aggregate function:

```
with Sample(region, openservices, dfc) as ( 
    values ('Karaci','14','4')
         , ('Lahore','13','3')
         , ('Islamabad','10','4')
), Second (region, openservices, dfc) as ( 
    values ('Karaci','14','4')
         , ('Lahore','10','3')
         , ('Islamabad','10','4')
) 
select region, substr(listagg(openservices,','),1,10), dfc 
from (
    select region, openservices, dfc 
    from sample 
    union 
    select region, openservices, dfc 
    from second
) 
group by region, dfc
```

The union will eliminate duplicate rows and the we can use listagg to concatenate openservices for the group region, dfc. Here I assumed that dfc is functionally dependent of region (according to you sample data). Since the return type of `LISTAGG` is a rather long string, I trimmed it down using substr.

Result:

```
REGION    2          DFC
--------- ---------- ---
Islamabad 10         4  
Karaci    14         4  
Lahore    10,13      3
```